# Convert simple function to arrange list into a one liner?

Tags: python

Trying to shorten this function I just wrote.

Given an array of (unsorted) integers, arrange them such that a < b > c < d > e...etc.

```
>>> swap([3,5,8,4,9,65,78,56])
[5, 8, 3, 4, 65, 78, 9, 56]
```

Here is what I have:

```
def swap(l):
 newlist=[]
 l.sort()
 for e in range(0,len(l)-1,2):
      newlist.append((l[e],l[e+1]))
 for e in range(0,len(newlist)-1,2):
      newlist[e],newlist[e+1]=newlist[e+1],newlist[e]
 return list(sum(newlist, ()))
```

Essentially, I'm sorting the list, swapping the adjacent two-pair tuples with a new list, and then flattening that new list.

Is there any shorter and/or faster way to do this using python conventions? Maybe a one liner? Thanks.

Comment: One line does not necessarily mean faster.

Comment: Yes, I know, but just trying to become more accustomed to this language and learn shorter ways to do simple things.

Comment: The example still does not satisfy the condition. 4 is not greater than 65.

Comment: Yeah I know, the function just swaps two pair tuples after sorting the list, trying to figure out how to fix that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
l = [...] #your list

l.sort()

l[::2],l[1::2] = l[1::2],l[::2]
```

Comment: This swaps the numbers in each pair of two, but does not satisfy the original arrangement of a < b > c < d > e. This results in [4, 3, 8, 5, 56, 9, 78, 65] when it should be [5, 8, 3, 4, 65, 78, 9, 56]

Comment: @jon234, The OP has shown just one possible arrangement. According to his criteria, multiple results are possible.

Comment: I think the original condition 'a < b > c < d > e' is wrong because it's not satisfied for OP's example.

Comment: Just realized that, yeah the second number does not satisfy it, need to fix that.